# Splitting field of $f(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n)$

Tags: field-theory

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n)$ over $K$. I need to prove that $L=K(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{n-1})$.
I know that I have to show $\alpha_n$ belongs to $K(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{n-1})$, but how do I do this?

Comment: What is the sum of all the roots?From there can you do something

Comment: @Riju is the sum of all the roots a coefficient of the polynomial?

Comment: Thats right if the polynomial is of degree n then sum of roots is -(coefficient of $x^{n-1}$). Check it for yourself!

Comment: Thank you! I will check it!

Comment: Show $ \alpha_{n} \in L $ then $ L / K \neq 0 $